# jsx doesn't seem to transpile correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-4, babeljs

I am using the react-rails gem in a Rails(4.2.7) project. This is the only modification I've made to my default Gemfile:

```
gem 'react-rails'
```

I've defined a component in a .jsx file using es6 syntax:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (<h1>hello</h1>)
  }
}
```

This works fine, but when I attempt to import a js module, I get an error:

```
import ReactTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-transition-group'
class Foo extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (<h1>hello</h1>)
  }
}
```

> foo.es6.self-69f3a42….js?body=1:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

It seems to me that if I'm not transpiling the jsx correctly then I would be getting an error in the first case, but I'm not. I've been using jsx all day long with no issues until I tried to use `import`.

I've tried adding the following to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'sprockets-es6'
gem 'babel-transpiler'
```

I've tried adding this to config/environments/development.rb:

```
config.react.jsx_transformer_class = React::JSX::BabelTransformer
```

And I've tried generating the component using the rails react component generator with the --es6 flag:

```
rails g react:component Foo --es6
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Actually your code did get transpiled properly by babel. The problem lies when you are importing. Youll need to use something like https://github.com/rstacruz/npm-pipeline-rails to get the npm modules into assets pipeline and then bundle it with the final js.

Answer (score 0):

So here's how I resolved my issue: since I'm using the 'react-rails' gem, the addons are available via a configuration option - I added the following to config/application.rb:

```
config.react.addons = true
```

Then in my .jsx file, instead of `import`, this is the syntax I used to have access to ReactTransitionGroup:

```
var ReactTransitionGroup = React.addons.ReactTransitionGroup
```

I still don't understand, but maybe someday I will, why the `import` statement transpiles to `require` which is undefined, and how that could be fixed by anything other than defining `require`, or transpiling to something that is defined.